# Google ads api v10: how to get metrics?

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I am working on a project to convert Python code that's using the soon-to-be-discontinued Adwords API to the new version Google Ads API v10.

I have a query that needs a few metrics, but when I use the main customer ID that works to connect, I get REQUESTED_METRICS_FOR_MANAGER error saying I need to "issue separate requests against each client account under the manager account".

How do I generate a client account to do this? I haven't seen any examples of this step.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account ids I needed were in a local MySQL database that a colleague on the project guided me to look at.

So in general: check with your management and colleagues ...